# Index created for PostgreSQL jsonb column not utilized

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have created an index for a field in jsonb column as:

```
create index on Employee using gin ((properties -> 'hobbies'))
```

Query generated is:

```
CREATE INDEX employee_expr_idx ON public.employee USING gin (((properties -> 'hobbies'::text)))
```

My search query has structure as:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee e
    WHERE e.properties @> '{"hobbies": ["trekking"]}'
    AND e.department = 'Finance'
```

Running EXPLAIN command for this query gives:

```
Seq Scan on employee e  (cost=0.00..4452.94 rows=6 width=1183)
    Filter: ((properties @> '{"hobbies": ["trekking"]}'::jsonb) AND (department = 'Finance'::text))
```

Going by this, I am not sure if index is getting used for search.

Is this entire setup ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you use in the WHERE clause must match the expression in the index **exactly**, your index uses the expression: `((properties -> 'hobbies'::text))` but your query only uses `e.properties` on the left hand side.

To make use of that index, your WHERE clause needs to use the same expression as was used in the index:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee e
WHERE (properties -> 'hobbies') @> '["trekking"]'
  AND e.department = 'Finance'
```

---

However: your execution plan shows that the table employee is really tiny (rows=6). With a table as small as that, a Seq Scan is always going to be the fastest way to retrieve data, no matter what kind of indexes you define.

Comment: How can I use it with spring data query. So input would be hobby. If I try to write native query as:
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Employee e " +
            "WHERE (e.properties -> 'hobbies') @> :hobby AND e.department = 'Finance' ", nativeQuery = true)

   hobby is framed as say, ["trekking"]. It refuses to identiy @>.